# Can a Messenger bot send messages to new users using their phone number through Facebook Messenger Customer Matching?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

I've been reading the documentation for Messenger's Customer Matching feature, and it is very unclear to me what it actually does.

My main question: through Customer Matching, can my page directly message people through their phone numbers without their having to message the page first?
If the answer is yes, then why hasn't this been working for me on my own phone number? I can send messages to myself after having messaged the page first, but receive a "No matching user found" error if I delete the conversation and have the bot message first.

If the answer's no, then what is the use of Customer Matching at all?
Please don't direct me to documentation, I've been through everything and this is still unclear. Would appreciate comments from those who have successfully used this feature. Thank you!

Comment: Is your phone number searchable and verified?

Comment: @WizKid yes it is!